# How do I get the handle to the Dialog Window

Tags: visual-c++

I want to get the handle to the MFC Dialog Window so I can get the coordinates of the window on the Desktop, so I can enlarge the window in its given position.
I need the handle for ::GetWindowRect(hWnd, lpRect)

thanks

Comment: Your dialog procedure receives the window handle.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

FindWindow might work.